# Определить форму экрана Android Wear программно

Tags: android, android-wear

Возможно ли программно определить форму дисплея Android Wear, т.е. является ли экран круглым или же квадратным(прямоугольным)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html):

> `Android Wear` позволяет определить форму экрана во время выполнения. Чтобы определить, квадратная или круглая форма экран, переопределите `onApplyWindowInsets()` метод в классе `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine` следующим образом:

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
    boolean mIsRound;
    int mChinSize;

    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
        mIsRound = insets.isRound();
        mChinSize = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
    }
    ...
}
```